# Is there a way I can create an array of cl::sycl::pipe?

Tags: c++, opencl, sycl

I am using the Xilinx's triSYCL github implementation,https://github.com/triSYCL/triSYCL.

I am trying to create a design with 100 `cl::sycl::pipes` each with `capacity= 6`. And I am gonna access each pipe through a separate thread in my SYCL code.

Here is what I tried:

```
constexpr int T = 6;
constexpr int n_threads = 100;

cl::sycl::pipe<cl::sycl::pipe<float>> p { n_threads, cl::sycl::pipe<float> { T } };

for (int j=0; j<n_threads; j++) {
    q.submit([&](cl::sycl::handler &cgh) {
      // Get write access to the pipe
      auto kp = p[j].get_access<cl::sycl::access::mode::write>(cgh);
      // Get read access to the data
      auto ba = A.get_access<cl::sycl::access::mode::read>(cgh);

      cgh.single_task<class producer>([=] () mutable {
          for (int i = 0; i != T; i++)
            // Try to write to the pipe up to success
            while (!kp.write(ba[i]));
        });
};
```

The code is just a copy of `tests/pipe/pipe_producer_consumer.cpp` file on the github repository. I have just added a `for loop` on it to parallely instantiate multiple threads.

I am getting multiple errors in this: `error: no matching function for call to ‘cl::sycl::pipe<cl::sycl::pipe<float> >::pipe(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   cl::sycl::pipe<cl::sycl::pipe<float>> p { n_threads, cl::sycl::pipe<float> { T } };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a disclaimer about the fact that `cl::sycl::pipe` are experimental things from the provisional SYCL 2.2 specification and that runs only on CPU (no accelerator, no FPGA...), and only in a very inefficient way.

But of course it is useful to experiment about how a real design would work and how SYCL can work.

A pipe is similar to some hardware FIFO.

You wrote

```
cl::sycl::pipe<cl::sycl::pipe<float>> p { n_threads, cl::sycl::pipe<float> { T } };
```

which means a `cl::sycl::pipe` to transfer some... `cl::sycl::pipe` to transfer some `float`! While it would be nice to beam some hardware like in Star Trek, it is not possible yet in the current version of SYCL to send real hardware through pipes. :-)

Probably a code like yours could work, but with a real array of pipes.
But the issue is that pipes need some size specified at construction time...

A few ideas I could think of would be `std::vector<cl::sycl::pipe<float>> p` and a loop doing `n_threads` `p.emplace_back(T)`.

Or you could use some metaprogramming (Boost.Hana might help...) to construct a `std::array<cl::sycl::pipe<float>>` from an initializer list of `n_threads` `T`.

Or you could use an intermediate object with a default construction doing the pipe you are interested in.

```
struct my_pipe : cl::sycl::pipe<float> {
  my_pipe() : pipe { T } {};
};

std::array<my_pipe, n_threads> p;
```

That said, I have not tried...

Furthermore, after thinking at it, I do not really see why in SYCL 2.2 the pipes could not have default constructors since they are just a wrappers around the OpenCL equivalent objects. I will push this to the SYCL committee. Thank you for making SYCL better. :-)

If all this makes sense, please post the final working code and make a pull-request on https://github.com/triSYCL/triSYCL with a new unit test code. :-)

If you are looking at some examples of metaprogramming with SYCL, look at
https://www.khronos.org/assets/uploads/developers/library/2017-supercomputing/Xilinx-triSYCL-complete_Nov17.pdf
slides 45--49
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4r6FXxknJEA

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Ronan. I am researching on SYCL, hence coming up with a lot of new questions. I'll try to see if this works. Thanks again.

Comment: There is a new proposal about pipes that you could be interested in and also contribute to the elaboration: https://github.com/intel/llvm/pull/635